# Cannot use VS Code to run node.js test

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to debug a jest test but it doesn't seem as though any config is running from launch.json. Only the attach configs work.

This is an example of the configs I am trying to run.

```json
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Jest Current File",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/jest",
            "args": [
                "${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "--config"
            ],
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
            "disableOptimisticBPs": true,
            "windows": {
                "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js"
            }
        }
```

When I attempt to run this config I end up with the following error

```
Message: "ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/Projects/PublicTransitGraph/node_modules/jest/bin/package.json'"

Stack:
"Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/Projects/PublicTransitGraph/node_modules/jest/bin/package.json'
at statSync (fs.js:1016:3)\n    at AsyncFunction.module.exports.sync (/home/Projects/PublicTransitGraph/node_modules/pkg-dir/node_modules/locate-path/index.js:57:17)
at runMatcher (/home/Projects/PublicTransitGraph/node_modules/pkg-dir/node_modules/find-up/index.js:54:22)
at AsyncFunction.module.exports.sync (/home/Projects/PublicTransitGraph/node_modules/pkg-dir/node_modules/find-up/index.js:67:21)
at AsyncFunction.module.exports.sync (/home/Projects/PublicTransitGraph/node_modules/pkg-dir/index.js:15:26)
at module.exports (/home/Projects/PublicTransitGraph/node_modules/import-local/index.js:7:27)\n    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/Projects/PublicTransitGraph/node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js:11:6)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)\n    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)"
```

I've changed from `workspaceFolder` to `workspaceRoot` but it doesn't seem to do anything.

It seems to be looking for a package.json in the bin folder for the jest module but there isn't any there. I don't know why its even looking there when running it through the command line doesn't give the error.

This is another config that I got directly from jest's [website](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/troubleshooting).

But when running this one the path gets appended incorrectly apparently and it gives me `no such file or directory` error

```json
        {
            "name": "Debug Jest Tests",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeArgs": [
              "--inspect-brk",
              "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js",
              "--runInBand"
            ],
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
            "port": 9229
        }
```

```
Message: "ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/Projects/PublicTransitGraph/node_modules/jest/bin/package.json'"

"Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/Projects/PublicTransitGraph/node_modules/jest/bin/package.json'
at statSync (fs.js:1016:3)
at AsyncFunction.module.exports.sync (/home/Projects/PublicTransitGraph/node_modules/pkg-dir/node_modules/locate-path/index.js:57:17)
at runMatcher (/home/Projects/PublicTransitGraph/node_modules/pkg-dir/node_modules/find-up/index.js:54:22)
at AsyncFunction.module.exports.sync (/home/Projects/PublicTransitGraph/node_modules/pkg-dir/node_modules/find-up/index.js:67:21)
at AsyncFunction.module.exports.sync (/home/Projects/PublicTransitGraph/node_modules/pkg-dir/index.js:15:26)
at module.exports (/home/Projects/PublicTransitGraph/node_modules/import-local/index.js:7:27)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/Projects/PublicTransitGraph/node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js:11:6)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)"
```

Answer (score 2):

Doing some more research it appears that turning off `Caught Exceptions` in the Breakpoint tab on the left fixes both of these issues.

Comment: This was the solution for me. What's up with this?